# How to show username on the welcome page

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms Form1 and Form2. Form1 contains two textBoxs for login details and Form2 contain a label just to show the username. I have this code but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Form1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=POS;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Select firstname, password from credentials", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string username = usernametxt.Text;
            string password = passwordtxt.Text;
            if (dr["username"].ToString() == username && dr["password"].ToString() == password)
            {
                Form2 hmpage = new Form2(username);

                hmpage.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The username or password you entered is incorrect!", "Logon Message!");
            }
        }
        con.Close();
        dr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public Form2(string strTextBox)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.Text = "Welcome to:(" + strTextBox + ")";
}
```

Comment: "I have this code but it doesn't work" - not good enough. Have you stepped through it with the debugger? What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: I haven't try the debugger... How will I do the debugger???

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you add breakpoints to some statements of your code for you to trace why it doesn't work. (press F5.. then F11 after adding breakpoints).

By then, you can add global variable, which can reside at Program.cs and assign the retrieved username.

[image]

Comment: there's something wrong on your connection string. better verify the connection.